# How to Work with Mercurial Server Repositories Without Supplying Credentials to Prompts or in .hgrc File

Tags: authentication, mercurial, windows-server-2008

I have a Windows 2008 R2 IIS7 server with Mercurial under HTTPS.  I connect to the Mercurial Repositories using TortoiseHG and via the web interface.

If I include my domain credentials in my ".hgrc" file I do not get prompted for domain username and password.
But if I do not have the credentials in the ".hgrc" file, I do get prompted for my domain credentials.

What I want, is to setup my Mercurial repositories security in such away that I do not have to supply credentials through a basic authentication prompt or via entering them in my personal ".hgrc" file.
The user access should be inferred by being logged into the domain on the computer I am working on.

Authentication setup:

- Anonymous Authentication - Disabled
- ASP.Net Impersonation - Disabled
- Basic Authentication - Enabled
- Forms Authentication - Disabled
- Windows Authentication - Enabled

On the client side I have my credentials in my personal ".hgrc":

```
[auth] 
tag.prefix = https://MercurialServer 
tag.username = Username 
tag.password = Password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Shane Madden](https://serverfault.com/users/72586/shane-madden) in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/256304/how-to-work-with-mercurial-server-repositories-without-supplying-credentials-to-p)